# Bluetooth Low Energy is not working on INTEL Nuc and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I am currently trying to connect my Intel NUC with Bluetooth 5.1 to my phone via Bluetooth Low Energy.

When I start a BLE scan from my phone I can't find the NUC. When I run a normal Bluetooth scan, I can find it.

Also, the command *sudo hcitool lescan* on the NUC returns an I/O Error. While *sudo hcitool scan* works perfect. Solution at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062037/hcitool-lescan-shows-i-o-error doesn't work for me.

Could it be that BLE is turned off or blocked somehow? Are there any settings to check this or enable it?

Intel NUC Version: NUC11TNKv7

Intel NUC OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Bluetooth Version: 5.1 (build in no dongle)

Output of *lspci -nnk* :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a14] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
    Kernel modules: i915
00:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a09] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a25] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:07.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a27] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a11] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
00:0d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a13] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:0d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a1b] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Device [2222:1111]
00:0d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a1d] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Device [2222:1111]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0ed] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0ef] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0e8] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0e9] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0e0] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:16.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0e3] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
    Kernel driver in use: serial
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0d3] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - SATA
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0b1] (rev 20)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a082] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0c8] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0a3] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0a4] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 [144d:a808]
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 [144d:a801]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
58:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:15f2] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3003]
    Kernel driver in use: igc
    Kernel modules: igc
```

You guys would help me tremendously....

Comment: Hello. Maybe it is just me but if you have no access to the computer and can not reboot it I can not see how you will trouble shoot it. Sure, Bluetooth can be turned off.

Comment: Hello, i have access to the computer. I could restart it. But it does not help. Bluetooth is activated and works. Only the BLE does not work.

Comment: It may not be supported by that hardware. Please review and edit your question as to what you can and can not do it is confusing.